# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update a row in mysql, however, error no 1024 comes up every time

```
@$name= $_POST['name'];
@$bio=$_POST['bio'];
    @$email=$_POST['email'];

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['bio']) && !empty($_POST['email']) )
{
     $result="SELECT * FROM accounts where email='$email'";
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$result),MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     $row['id']=$id;
     $Sql_Query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE profile SET name= '$name', bio = '$bio' WHERE id = '$id'");

if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
 echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
else{
echo 'Something went wrong, whether id is not present or something else'.mysqli_error($con);
}
}else
{
    echo 'missing parameters';
}
```

error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: we need to know the full error.

Comment: Oh I know what it is, heh. Real simple here; you executed the same query twice and you're most likely getting a "1" back as the error, right? Edit: heh, knew it ;-)

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Btw, you're leaving yourself open to a serious SQL injection here. Use a prepared statement.

Comment: Actually, i am using procedural method, will it be ok to use prepared statment in this

Comment: @ScofLj You can use a prepared statement in both Object oriented or procedural styles. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php with examples you can try. Just don't go executing the query twice as you did.

Comment: Which of these queries throws that error? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See the edit near the bottom).

What happened here is that you executed the same query twice for the UPDATE and the error that you should be getting is a "1". (This before the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51677698/3)).

Change your

```
$Sql_Query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE profile SET name= '$name', bio = '$bio' WHERE id = '$id'");
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
```

to just

```
if($Sql_Query){
 echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
```

and use a prepared statement to help against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement (General information).
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (MySQLi_).
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (PDO).

---

As per [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51677698/3) where you added:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

...which is what I suspected and posted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677698/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your/51677779#comment90318652_51677698) earlier.

By the way; those `@` characters are error suppressors and should be removed during development.

Using [PHP's error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would help to a certain extent, but not for those @'ed variables for the POST arrays should there be anything wrong for them.

---

Edit:

As stated in a comment given by [IncredibleHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960971/incrediblehat), this line:

```
$row['id']=$id;
```

is reversed and should be written as:

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

The id is to be assigned "to" the row and not the other way around.

I failed to see that, my bad. Good catch on that.

Comment: thanks, the error is gone, but the record is not updating

Comment: @ScofLj Welcome. See what `mysqli_error($con);` shows then. If it's not throwing an error, then your query may have failed silently. One possible reason would be the wrong datatype, or a column length's being too short. There could be other factors also.

Comment: @ScofLj You might even be trying to update a column (ior columns) that may have a constraint on it and now since it already possibly exists, it's not letting you. It's hard to say since now, we'd need to see the schema and value examples from it and what data is being processed in the POST arrays.

Comment: It 'not updating' is most likely because he is doing: `$row['id']=$id;` ... instead of `$id=$row['id'];`

Comment: @IncredibleHat Oh man, good catch!!!! Wow, that totally escaped me *lol!* I'll add that to the answer if you don't mind :-)

Comment: @ScofLj There was a comment given by another member here and I've made the edit for it, so you will need to reload the answer. This about `$row['id']=$id;`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Please don't delete your comment and thanks for that :-)

Comment: You're welcome @ScofLj glad to see that this was resolved and with a bit of help from [IncredibleHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960971/incrediblehat) I might add :-)  he deserves thanks also. Edit: Oh you did :-) *Cheers!*

Comment: Eh, I just mentioned a goof... Funk did all the work here :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat Actually, you were of tremendous help, really; don't underestimate yourself :-) I'm glad you stepped in because chances are that I may not have caught that.